# update nested Object data without changing Object Id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am currently using array filters to update the nested object.
My structure is -

```
Category Collection - 
{
  name:Disease,
  _id:ObjectId,
  subCategory:[{
    name:Hair Problems,
    _id:ObjectId,
    subSubCategory:[{
       name: Hair Fall,
       _id:ObjectId
    },{
       name: Dandruff,
       _id:ObjectId
    }]
  }]
}
```

I want to update the subsubcategory with id 1.1.1 which I am doing by using array filters.

```
let query = { 'subCategories.subSubCategories._id': subSubId };
let update = { $set: { 'subCategories.$.subSubCategories.$[j]': data } };
let option = { arrayFilters: [{ 'j._id': subSubId }], new: true };

await Categories.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, option
```

This code is working fine but array filters change the object id of subsubCategory. Is there any other alternative to do so without changing the ObjectId.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which property do you want to update exactly?

Comment: user can update any property present in subsubCategory @AmitDas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the keys which you are getting as payload and put inside the `$set` operator.

```
const data = {
  firstKey: "key",
  secondKey: "key2",
  thirdKey: "key3"
}
const object = {}

for (var key in data) {
  object[`subCategories.$.subSubCategories.$[j].${key}`] = data[key]
}

let query = { 'subCategories.subSubCategories._id': subSubId };
let update = { '$set': object };
let option = { 'arrayFilters': [{ 'j._id': subSubId }], 'new': true };

await Categories.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, option)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in `$set` line there you have not mentioned specific fields to be update instead `subCategory.$.subSubCategory.$[j]` will replace complete object element that matches the _id filter. Hence your _id field is also getting updated. You have to explicitly mention the field name after array element identifier. See example below:

Suppose you want to update `name` field in `subSubCategories` from `Dandruff` to `new Dandruff`. Then do this way:

`let update = { $set: { 'subCategories.$.subSubCategories.$[j].name': "new Dandruff" } };`

This will only update `name` field in `subSubCategories` array

Comment: I am updating multiple fields at the same time, so do i have to mention every field.